# Cannot get emails

Tags: iphone, email

I have an iPhone 6. I have successfully configured exchange account onto it.
The problem I have is that sometimes i cannot connect to the server; meanwhile other colleagues using iPhone 6, and other phones like samsung can connect to the same server.

I have the same iOS and everybody in the company. I am using the same mobile operator as everybody to connect to the server. Usually I don't do anything, sometimes after 2 days, everything start working again.

Any idea about what can cause this?

Comment: is the push option checked on the emails settings ?

Answer (score 1):

You should check with your company's IT, because there are so many things that could be the cause, that it's basically pointless listing all possible causes here.

First off my mind, verify that the settings are truly correct and identical to on "your colleagues" phones... Next it may be a WiFi/Cellular Signal issue? And so on, and so on... Check with your IT.

Comment: fortunately i am the IT person in charge and the phone belong to my MD.

Comment: @BrunoC please elaborate in more detail what you mean with "I cannot connect to the server" - what error message do you get? How did you setup the exchange account on your phone? Have you tried your exchange account on a second phone and experience the same behaviour (= Is it phone related or more likely your Exchange account...)?